# Xcode simulator shows blank screen until quitting debugger

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I'm following along with the Stanford Winter 2015 introduction to Swift on ItunesU to create a custom view controller (I'm using Xcode 7). I have created a custom view as well that currently just implements two circles using UIBezierPath (my code for my drawRect function is below, I believe this is the only code in my project pertaining to the simple display I expect to see in the simulator. My custom view controller is empty and I have removed the view did load function). I have made this custom View Controller the initial view controller, and am not using a home screen. I have used @IBDesignable in my view to demonstrate what I expect to see in my storyboard, which is shown in the first picture below (which is currently only a link since I can't embed yet being a new member). When I build and run my project to start the simulator I see a black screen with the apple logo, and then once the simulator loads I get a completely blank screen (as seen below in picture 2.) Now the reason I find this odd is because I am able to view what I expect to see in my storyboard, and I can perform the following steps to get my app to display in the simulator, but it is really annoying to do every time:

1. While the simulator is running, click the "stop button" in xcode to end the debugger. This takes the simulator back to the home screen.
2. From the home screen of the simulator, run my app.
3. My simple display now shows up properly in the simulator, as I see it in the story board. (this would be shown in picture 3, but I am unable to post more than 2 links being a newbie)

 PICTURES:
[Storyboard view of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxc0I.png)

[Blank screen after starting simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saAUc.png)

[Simulator with app properly displayed][3]

In addition to this simple display, I have attempted to add NSAttributed strings, and after doing this the annoying trick I use to get my app to display in the simulator no longer works. However, I also noticed that the "annoying trick" to get it to display will still work if I leave out certain attributes on my attributed strings. Also, I don't get any error messages in the console output, the only output is "(lldb)." So does anyone have any ideas why the display doesn't show up properly when I run the simulator from xcode?

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let checkOutButtonCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: inOutCircleCenter("Out"), radius: InCircleRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)
    let checkInButtonCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: inOutCircleCenter("In"), radius: InCircleRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)
    checkInButtonCircle.lineWidth = lineWidth
    checkOutButtonCircle.lineWidth = lineWidth
    backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor() 
    color.set()
    //draw the actual circle
    checkInButtonCircle.stroke()
    checkOutButtonCircle.stroke()
    }
```

Comment: Can you check your pictures again? I see the same one in both cases, and it isn't what I expected to see in either case.

Comment: Pictures have been updated to the proper images (guess that's why they limit noobs with the pics since they don't do it right the first time ;)

Comment: It is quite difficult to find a problem without seeing the full source code. If you can please upload it through GitHub

Comment: I didn't want to include my project because I have an overload of multiline comments reminding myself of swift syntax, so I thought it was too messy to include. But the breakpoints answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can happen if you have a breakpoint set. It might be dumping you into the debugger before the UI is initialized, resulting in a blank screen. When you launch it from the simulator home screen, the debugger is not attached, so your breakpoint does not stop the code.

Look in the breakpoints tab of the leftmost column in Xcode. If you see breakpoints, which look like this:

[image]

…then click on them and press the delete key to remove them.

Comment: Wonderful! I had a surprisingly large number of breakpoints I must have accidentally set by clicking wildly along the gutter. I didn't ever realize I had breakpoints set so I never stepped through any of them.